# ASP.NET MVC 3 URL.Action mapped to incorrect Route

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, url-routing, url.action

I have these two routes configured in my app:

```
routes.MapRoute(
             "PromotionModel-test", // Route name
             "testSpecifications", // URL with parameters
             new { controller = "test", action = "Brochure", modelName = "test", groupID = 0 } // Parameter defaults
         );

routes.MapRoute(
          "", // Route name
          "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
          new { groupID = 0, controller = "Home", action = "List", id = UrlParameter.Optional, CatID = 0 },
          new {controller = @"\w{3,}"}
        );
```

When I call

```
 @Url.Action("Brochure", "test")
```

the url it generated is  "/testSpecifications" instead of "test/Brochure". When I explicitly do

```
@Url.Action("Brochure", "test", new { modelName = string.Empty })
```

Then it will produce the correct result.

I know there is segment variable reuse scenario, but how does it apply here? What's the logic behind the scene?

## Updates

What I want to achieve here is to simply produce the URL I had above without having to explicitly set any parameter values.

Imagine you started developing a website, where it didn't require any parameters. Later on, you have notice you might need to add several addition parameters, in the example above, the new parameter added is "modelName". And then you client request to map the "testSpecifications" to map to the specific page like the one above.

We definitely don't want to go back to update all the Url.Action to set the default values for each of them. What approach would you take to deal with this?

Hope this make sense....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Kasper mentioned above, with the route below, the value in the "modelName" is been used as an "default" value instead of a constrain to check against.

```
routes.MapRoute(
             "PromotionModel-test", // Route name
             "testSpecifications", // URL with parameters
             new { controller = "test", action = "Brochure", modelName = "test", groupID = 0 } // Parameter defaults
         );
```

So the key to resolve the issue is to make it a constrain rather than just default value. Here is the correct route configuration that resolves my issue.

I was surprised myself when seen it mapping correctly for both incoming request(localhost/testSpecifications) and url generation (Url.Action("Brochure,Test")...

```
 routes.MapRoute(
                 "PromotionModel-test", // Route name
                 "testSpecifications", // URL with parameters
                 new { controller = "test", action = "Brochure", modelName = "test", groupID = 0 },
               new { modelName="test"}
             );
```

Answer (score 3):

The logic is really simple as a matter of fact. The routes takes precedence in the order of declaration. And since `"Url.Action("Brochure" "test")` matches the first route, it is only natural that is is the one that MVC use.

In the second case you explicityly set `modelName` which means that it no longer matches the first route. This leaves the default route.

**Update**
You can map the url '/testSpecifications' to an action with default values just like you did above:

```
routes.MapRoute(
      "PromotionModel-test", // Route name
      "testSpecifications", // URL with parameters
      new { controller = "test", action = "Brochure", modelName = "test", groupID = 0});
```

However, if you at any point want to generate this url with a different value for `modelName` then you will have to bind this parameter to the URL:

```
routes.MapRoute(
     "PromotionModel-test", // Route name
     "testSpecifications/{modelName}", // URL with parameters
      new { controller = "test", action = "Brochure", modelName = "test", groupID = 0}); 
    );
```

With the above route, you can either just link to '/testSpecifications' in which case the default values for modelName will be used, or you can explicityly set the value for the modelName: '/testSpecifications/SomeModelName'.

Comment: erm....How does it match the first route? It requires the model name to be "test". I did not pass model name at all in the "Url.Action("Brochure" "test")"

Comment: Nope, you set the default value of modelName to test.

Comment: So are you saying if I don't specifically set the model name, it will match the first route, because the action and controller names matched and the rest parameter will be treat as the default value instead of using it as an requirement for it to match?

Comment: It matches the first because the controller and action values match.

Comment: Try to explain what you're trying to achieve. It sounds like you're getting off track at the moment. Trying to solve a problem with the wrong tool.

Comment: What I want to achieve here is to simply produce the URL I had above without having to explicitly set any parameter values. What are the ways to do it?

Comment: Hey mate, thanks a lot for your help! I must have not express my question clear enough and misleaded you .. ..but thanks for all those useful information. I unfortunately I am not able to vote up for you due to my poor reputation. But thanks for your help!! FYI, I've found a way around it and will post it tmr....

Comment: You're welcome. Consider selecting this as the accepted answer if you believe it so :)